# Join on Table valued function in select query

Tags: sql-server

I have `ques` table:

[image: Ques table]

and i have user defined `split` function:

```
Select * from split('1,2,3,4')
```

which returns data in table format by splitting string as below

[image: Data returned by Split()]

i want to write select query on `ques` table with split function to get data like below:

`id |  ques | tags`
`-----------------`
`1  |  abc  |  1`
`2  |  def  |  1`
`2  |  def  |  2`
`3  |  ghi  |  2`
`4  |  jkl  |  3`
`4  |  jkl  |  4`

Can any one help me to make this join??

Comment: when I do things similar to this, I like to Declare a table and put the results in that, then join the declared table onto the other items I am looking for.

Comment: You should slap whoever designed this table. You don't store multiple values in a single column.

Comment: Agreed on @Kermit comment wrt slapping.

Comment: @Kermit, if you can't solve this problem it doesn't mean that the database is wrong. it's require to store data in this way.

Comment: @DhavalPtl I can solve the problem the wrong way and the right way. I prefer to solve the problem the right way. And yes, the database design is wrong.

Comment: @DhavalPtl This is a DB design anti-pattern for a lot of reasons, not least of which it's incredibly inefficient to locate data inside that concatenated column. It also means you can't have any referential integrity constraints set up, and will cause all manner of headaches down the road.

Answer (score 4):

You need a [numbers table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) to efficiently parse the comma-separated string. You do it in a subquery cross-applied to the table:

```
select *
from ques
cross apply (
    select substring(tags, n, charindex(',', tags + ',', n) - n)
    from numbers 
    where substring(',' + tags, n, 1) = ','
    and n < len(tags) + 1
) x (c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mr Dean's Method is very creative but I think you can keep things simple by just using the same split function you are using along with `CROSS APPLY` see below:

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT, ques VARCHAR(10), Tags VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(1 , 'ABC', '1'),(2 , 'Def', '1,2'),(3 , 'ghi', '2'),
(4 , 'jkl', '3,4'),(5 , 'mno', '4,5')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT t.ID, t.ques, C.items AS Tags
FROM @TABLE t
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(t.Tags, ',')) C
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ ques ║ Tags  ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ ABC  ║     1 ║
║  2 ║ Def  ║     1 ║
║  2 ║ Def  ║     2 ║
║  3 ║ ghi  ║     2 ║
║  4 ║ jkl  ║     3 ║
║  4 ║ jkl  ║     4 ║
║  5 ║ mno  ║     4 ║
║  5 ║ mno  ║     5 ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════╝
```